# Integration: $\int\frac{1}{(x^2+x+1)^{1/2}} dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Find the value of $$\int\frac{1}{(x^2+x+1)^{1/2}} dx$$

Anyone can provide hint on how to integrate this, and how you know what method to use? (I mean, is there any general guideline to follow for solving?)

Thank you!

Comment: set $\sqrt{x^2+x+1}=x+t$

Comment: complete the squares $x^2+x+1=(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}$ and use trigonometric substitution.

Comment: @AnuragA im stuck here : ln |sec u+tan u| where u =tan^-1 (x+0.5/(0.75)^0.5), how to resolve this?thx!

Comment: When you see something like this, the first thing you should think of is completing the square.  That seems to be a weak point in many students' grasp of these things. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy But then after completing the square, Im stuck at here:                 ln |sec u+tan u| where u =tan^-1 (x+0.5/(0.75)^0.5)

Answer (score 3):

If you make the Euler substitution $t=x+\sqrt{x^2+x+1}$, then $\displaystyle x=\frac{t^2-1}{2t+1}$ and $\displaystyle dx=\frac{2(t^2+t+1)}{(2t+1)^2}dt$;

so $\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}dx=\int\frac{1}{t-\frac{t^2-1}{2t+1}}\cdot\frac{2(t^2+t+1)}{(2t+1)^2}dt=\int\frac{2}{2t+1}dt=\ln\lvert2t+1\lvert+C$

$\displaystyle=\ln\left(2x+2\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+1\right)+C$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Notice that  $$x^2 + x + 1 = \Big(x  +\frac{1}{2}\Big)^{2}  +\frac{3}{4} $$

Use $x + \frac{1}{2}= \frac{\sqrt 3}{2} \sinh t $.

Comment: $x+\frac12=\frac{\sqrt3}2\tan(t)$ is also useful

Comment: @robjohn It is!

Answer (score 2):

$\bf{My\; Solution:: }$ Let $\displaystyle I = \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}dx = \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2}}dx$

Now Let $\displaystyle \left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right) = t\;,$ Then $dx = dt$ and $\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = a>0$

So Integral $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+a^2}}dt$$

Now Let $t^2+a^2 = y^2\;,$ Then $$\displaystyle tdt = ydy \Rightarrow \frac{dt}{y} = \frac{dy}{t}=\frac{d(t+y)}{(t+y)}$$

So Integral $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{dt}{y} = \int\frac{d(t+y)}{(t+y)}= \ln \left|t+y\right|+\mathcal{C}$$

So $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}dx = \ln \left|\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\sqrt{x^2+x+1}\right|+\mathcal{C}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}=\int\frac1{\sqrt{(x+1/2)^2+3/4}}=\ln|x+1/2+\sqrt{x^2+x+1}|+{\rm\color{grey}{ constant}}$$