# How can I find $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + x + 1}} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, polynomials, indefinite-integrals

My question is, how can I evaluate the following integral? Am I supposed to use Euler substitution here or is there a simpler way?

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + x + 1}} dx$$

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integration: $\int\frac{1}{(x^2+x+1)^{1/2}} dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1246836/integration-int-frac1x2x11-2-dx) – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7Bx%5E2%20%2B%20x%20%2B%201%7D%7D%20dx%24&p=1)

Comment: Do you know how to complete the square?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

By completing the square and rescaling the variable, you will reduce the radicand to the form $t^2+1$, which calls for an inverse hyperbolic sine.